# RxJS - check array of observables with concurrency in interval

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

Working on a scheduler with RxJS that every second checks the array of jobs. When job is finished it is removed from array. I would like to run that with the **.mergeAll(concurrency)** parameter so for example there are only two jobs running at the same time.
Currently I have an workaround which can be seen [here](https://github.com/bleenco/abstruse/blob/master/src/api/process-manager.ts#L54-L83).

What I am trying is something like

```
Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .timeInterval()
  .merge(...jobProcesses.map(job => Observable.fromPromise(startJob(job.id))))
  .mergeAll(config.concurrency || 10)
  .subscribe();
```

which obviously doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've already got a flat observable after `merge`, I don't understand what the second `mergeAll` is supposed to do. It isn't clear what you mean by "every second checks the array of jobs" either, each job is a promise, so you don't have to poll it. Once it's done, it'll complete, tick the observable it's wrapped in, and cause it to complete, thus appearing in the merged observable.

Comment: Stepping away from Rx for a minute, what are you trying to do in plain English? Do you just need to take an array of jobs and receive all of their results, with some limitation on the concurrency?

Comment: Asad that's true. I would like some limitation on the concurrency. What I would also like is that if I add for example 5 new items to that array it is still processed with limitation on the concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it seems you are simply trying to limit concurrency, and this interval stuff is just a detour. You should be able to get what you need with:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx')

let startTime = 0
const time = () => {
    if (!startTime)
        startTime = new Date().getTime()
    return Math.round((new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000)
}

const jobs = new Rx.Subject() // You may additionally rate-limit this with bufferTime(x).concatAll()
const startJob = j => Rx.Observable.of(undefined).delay(j * 1000).map(() => time())
const concurrency = 2

time()
jobs
    .bufferCount(concurrency)
    .concatMap(buf => Rx.Observable.from(buf).flatMap(startJob))
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x))

Rx.Observable.from([3, 1, 3]).subscribe(jobs)

// The last job is only processed after the first two are completed, so you see:
// 1
// 3
// 6
```

Note that this technically isn't squeezing out the maximum amount of concurrency possible, since it breaks the jobs up into constant batches. If your jobs have significantly uneven processing times, the longest job in the batch will delay pulling work from the next batch.

Comment: sorry for being unclear about the question though but you are missing the important part. I would like that in interval of 1s array of jobs is checked if there are any new jobs but still work  with concurrency rate of possible previous jobs.

Comment: @JanKuri Why are you using an array in the first place? It sounds like the original job queue should be a subject, which you can rate limit however you please using `bufferTime`.

Comment: for a better presentation; I am working on CI integration server and this are builds running in docker container in the background. so yes, each job can run significant amount of time but will like to maintain the concurrency of parallel jobs stored in the config.

Comment: i.e. `const jobs = new Subject().bufferTime(1000)` (although I don't see why you need the additional rate limiting here), and whenever you want: `jobs.next(/* your new job */)`.

Comment: @JanKuri An array is the wrong data structure to model something that is changing over time (as you say you want to check it every 1000 seconds). You should be using a subject, not an array.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for, can you update an answer regarding to Subject and will accept it right off. thanks!